# Issues with calling a function that has to wait for a server response

Tags: ios, json, swift, alamofire, completionhandler

So I have the following code in my view controller that works perfectly. I make the json request, the server call is made and I get the response no issues. My function is called on a button click:

```
@IBAction func buttonClick(sender: AnyObject) {

        var postsEndpoint = "http://test.com/test"
        let test = ["Blah":"test"]

        request(.POST, postsEndpoint, parameters: test as! [String : AnyObject]   , encoding: .JSON)
            .responseJSON { (request, response, data, error) in

                if let anError = error
                {
                    // got an error in getting the data, need to handle it
                    println("error calling POST on /posts")
                    println(error)
                }
                else if let data: AnyObject = data
                {

                    let post = JSON(data)
                    // now we have the results, let's just print them though a tableview would definitely be better UI:
                     println("The post is: " + post.description)
                }
        }
}
```

So now I want to make a class that I can use for calling all my services. So I have then created a function in this class that I am calling from my view controller using 
let invoke = WebServiceCall()
let jsonrequest = invoke.InvokeService()

So my class and function are

```
class WebServiceCall{


    var post:JSON = nil

    func InvokeService(type : String) ->JSON{

        var postsEndpoint = "http://test.com/test"
        let test = ["Blah":"test"]


        request(.POST, postsEndpoint, parameters: test as! [String : AnyObject]   , encoding: .JSON)
            .responseJSON { (request, response, data, error) in


                if let anError = error
                {
                    // got an error in getting the data, need to handle it
                    println("error calling POST on /posts")
                    println(error)
                }
                else if let data: AnyObject = data
                {

                    self.post = JSON(data)
                    // now we have the results, let's just print them though a tableview would definitely be better UI:
                     println("The post is: " + post.description)
                }
        }

        return self.post

    }
```

I think my issue is that the function is called but because there is no completion handler to wait for the response that I never get the data returned.
I have googled completion handlers but I am getting confused.
Any help would be great thx

Comment: Several things you could do. One could be to add a completion handler as a parameter to InvokeService.  Then your view controller passes a completion handler to  InvokeService, so that when the jason is available your view controller's completion handler gets called.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
var post:JSON = nil

func InvokeService(type : String) ->JSON{

var postsEndpoint = "http://test.com/test"
let test = ["Blah":"test"]


request(.POST, postsEndpoint, parameters: test as! [String : AnyObject]   , encoding: .JSON)
    .responseJSON { (request, response, data, error) in


        if let anError = error
        {
            // got an error in getting the data, need to handle it
            println("error calling POST on /posts")
            println(error)
        }
        else if let data: AnyObject = data
        {

            self.post = JSON(data)
            // now we have the results, let's just print them though a tableview would definitely be better UI:
             println("The post is: " + post.description)
        }
}

return self.post

}
```

Change this to

```
var post:JSON = nil

func InvokeService(type : String, compHandler: (NSRequest, NSresponse, NSData, NSError) -> Void){

var postsEndpoint = "http://test.com/test"
let test = ["Blah":"test"]


request(.POST, postsEndpoint, parameters: test as! [String : AnyObject]   , encoding: .JSON)
    .responseJSON { (request, response, data, error) in
    compHandler(request, response, data, error)
}

}
```

And then you can call this method

NOTE:
This code has not been tested. so maybe you need to change a little bit.

Comment: Excuse my ignorance but how then do I call that service as the compHandler is confusing me, its not building as its saying the NSRequest in compHandler is 'Use of undeclared type NSrequest' ?? Thanks for the swift response :)

Comment: Well Change NSRequest to the correct type. when you call request(.POST, postsEndpoint, parameters: test as! [String : AnyObject]   , encoding: .JSON)
    .responseJSON { (request, response, data, error) in  

What are the types of request, response data and error ?

Comment: So I have got the parameters set but I'm still unsure how do i call the invoke service function now and how do i return my json object?

Comment: @Jack Swift will help you. make a new object of the class WebServiceCall, then call the method on that object. enter the first parameter. then press tab then press enter, then tab then press enter. hope it's clear. I cannot write code of you since I don''t have the library you're using.

Comment: So I am calling my function like this                                                              let jsonResponse = invoke.InvokeService("authentication", compHandler: { (NSURLRequest, NSHTTPURLResponse, AnyObject, NSError) -> Void in})    The function is being called but again its as if its not waiting for the response.  Have debugged and it just steps thru function but there is not waiting for response. I'm using Alamofire, thx for your input @Omar Al-Shammary

Comment: @Jack ok. After void in, you put your code and parse the response. Or other wise use protocol and callback

Comment: Thx @Omar Al-Shammary  thats worked perfectly. Thanks for your help

Answer (score 0):

You can't return the JSON from asynchronous call because returning happens synchronously. The JSON isn't guaranteed to be available (and likely isn't) when it's time to return from the method.

One fix:

- Remove `->JSON` from your method signature and `return self.post` from your body
- Make a new method like `func parseJSON(JSON : JSON)` to do whatever you want with the JSON
- Call this method from within your completion handler

Inside the `parseJSON(:_)` method you can pass the JSON (or any other objects) back to your view controller. This is typically done via delegation, a completion handler (as Gruntcakes mentioned in the comments), or an `NSNotification`.

Comment: But this doesn't address how he can get the jason back to the calling view controller, or how the vc knows when the jason is available, which I think is what he wants to do.

Comment: Sure it does. He can do all of that in the `parseJSON` method.

Comment: Yes but he doesn't know how to do that, that's actually the point of his question. The larger picture of his question, not a narrow focus, is how to migrate his call from his view controller into a dedicated class. Your answer is totally correct, but misses a vital part of that connection that he won't know how to do as he is struggling with blocks and asynchronicity.

Comment: OK, I added a bit more information. (Feel free to also post your own answer.)

Comment: You got here first, don't want to trounce your answer ;-)

Comment: so this is how I am calling my function,let jsonResponse = invoke.InvokeService("test", compHandler: { (NSURLRequest, NSHTTPURLResponse, AnyObject, NSError) -> Void in })   Which is calling the function but again it just calls the function but it doesn't look like its waiting for the response. I'm using alamofire, thx for your input @Omar Al-Shammary